# Locate points that are within a certain distance of other points in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I need a way of locating all points in my dataset that are within a certain distance of any other point. For example, in the following data set in which EASTING AND NORTHING are British National Grid coordinates (to the nearest metre); I need to identify points which are within 5 meters of other points (ID #s 01 and 03 in this example). Can someone please suggest a QGIS technique for accomplishing this?

```
ID   EASTING    NORTHING
01   297736 703033
02   297991 702934
03   297735 703034
04   299488 702670
05   299476 762627
06   299443 702669
07   299164 702448
08   299210 702444
```

Comment: Is your dataset in a shapefile or other spatial data format? if so, you can perform a spatial join in QGIS to get the distance: http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2013/04/tutorial-nearest-neighbor-analysis.html

Comment: This is a comment because I only *know* it will work in ArcGIS, but the steps are so simple I think it should be replicable in QGIS. Buffer all points by search radius without dissolve (so each buffer is a unique poly). Select all buffers that intersect buffers, then select all points that intersect the selected buffers. Those should be all points with another point within search radius.

Comment: But can this be done when all the points reside in the same layer?

Comment: If by 'this' you mean the spatial join that @mapBaker suggests, yes it can (in either ArcGIS or in QGIS, as pointed out in the updated tutorial linked at the link he provided - blue text box, says just use the same layer for input and target). My buffering solution should work regardless of number of layers, but might take more selection steps.

Answer (score 9):

Vector -> Analysis Tools -> Distance Matrix will create a CSV output of the distances between each point.  You can then select all rows that are 5 or less.  Then join your table to your point data, and only points that join are within 5 meters of another point.

Answer (score -3):

If you have access to ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced, the "Near" tool can handle this situation. Just have the input features and near features point to the same layer.

Help:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001q000000

Comment: Sorry, but I need a QGIS solution.

Comment: Ok, can't help you there. Maybe this answer will help someone else down the line. :)